# C++ DLL Injection "CreateRemoteThread" returning 0

Tags: c++, windows, dll, code-injection, dll-injection

So I'm writing a program for DLL injection, using OpenProcess, VirtualAllocEx, WriteProcessMemory, etc.

Everything (appears) to be running smoothly until I call CreateRemoteThread. I triple-checked the Microsoft documentation and looked at a few examples, so I'm pretty sure I've used the function properly, however it's returning 0.

Here's my code:

```
// path to DLL
LPCSTR dllPath = "C:\\Users\\user\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\dllname.dll";

// process handle
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 9440);

// dll base address
LPVOID baseAddress = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, strlen(dllPath) + 1, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

// write to process memory
WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, baseAddress, (LPCVOID) dllPath, strlen(dllPath) + 1, NULL);

// kernel32's LoadLibraryA function
LPVOID loadLibrary = (LPVOID) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

// create remote thread -- This is what returns 0 (not sure why)
HANDLE hLoadThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) loadLibrary, baseAddress, 0, 0);

// wait to inject
WaitForSingleObject(hLoadThread, INFINITE);

// print debugs
std::cout << "Successfully injected." << std::endl << std::endl;
std::cout << hProcess << std::endl;
std::cout << baseAddress << std::endl;
std::cout << loadLibrary << std::endl;
std::cout << hLoadThread << std::endl;
std::cin.get();

// free memory
VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, baseAddress, strlen(dllPath) + 1, MEM_RELEASE);
```

And here's the output to the console:

```
Successfully injected.

0x110
0x3a9c0000
0x75dd0bd0
0 <-- this is the return value of CreateRemoteThread
```

I've tried fidgeting with the null/0s in the parameters and removing the WaitForSingleObject call but neither gives a result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread) `"If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError."` So, what does `GetLastError()` say?

Comment: It gave error 5 (access denied), but I'm running the executable as administrator so I'm not really sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. I was compiling with MingGW 32 bit instead of using 64 bit, so I created a VS solution and it fixed. Thank you for the help @Retired Ninja.

Comment: Were you perhaps tryimg to inject a 32bit DLL into a 64bit process?

Comment: Yes this was the issue, for some reason I downloaded a 32-bit binary of MinGW.